Which regex can I use to replace Greek capital vocals with tonos to ones without it, in Bulk Rename Utility application?
I would like to replace in a lot of filenames, the Greek capital vocals with tonos, with the ones without it:
Ά > Α
Έ > Ε
Ή > Η
Ί > Ι
Ό > Ο
Ύ > Υ
Ώ > Ω

I know how to replace them one by one, but I think RegEx is the best approach, to replace all of them at once.
Can someone help me with the syntax, please?
Thanks.

What is the Operating System?

@RichardoBohner - sorry for i wasn't clear enough. It's about the Bulk Rename Utility (link) that I'm using in Windows 11.

General FYI: Windows natively supports bulk renaming via PowerRename (part of PowerToys). I only mention this because the Bulk Rename Utility software doesn't seem trustworthy because its site throws up a lot of red flags (no .com address, no links with information about the developer/company, etc.). There was a utility with the exact same name that looked similar to this one, which development stopped on years ago, with no trustworthy site to download it from.

"Red flags (no .com address)"? What kind of utter nonsense is that?

.co.uk's generally fairly trustworthy. Its not like say .cc or those vanity TLDs, its a real country.

There's no way to do it weith regex as others have said - it's not what their purpose is. I won't go into details as it has been explained well.
If you want to use this software, you can use its Character translations... feature available in Special dropdown.
Simply add some pairs into the window, such as:
Ά=A
Ή=Η
Ώ=Ω

etc., where = is a separator of target and replacement and each entry is in a new line. Then check the Character translations checkbox and run it on your files:


There is no syntax for that. While a regex can be used to match all of them, it won't really help much with replacement – that in itself is already outside of what a regex does; there is no regex syntax to specify what which match should be replaced with. The program that does the regex match still needs to "manually" map each match to its replacement.
In short, it depends on the multi-rename tool and not on the regex.
If this were on Linux, I would use perl-rename (aka prename) as it's arbitrarily programmable, though in this case the simplest option of chaining multiple regular substitutions would do the job. (Perl also has a character substitution operator y/// that looks like regex but isn't.)
prename "s/Ά/Α/g; s/Έ/Ε/g; s/Ή/Η/g; s/Ί/Ι/g; s/Ό/Ο/g; s/Ύ/Υ/g; s/Ώ/Ω/g" ./Docs/*.pdf

prename "%r = ('Ά' => 'Α', 'Έ' => 'Ε', ...); s/[ΆΈ...]/\$r{\$&}/ge" ./Docs/*.pdf


Well if you don't mind using powershell. It is also included in Windows you could use something like this:
get-childitem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {($_.name).replace('Ά','A').replace('Έ','E').replace('Ή','H').replace('Ί','I').replace('Ό','O').replace('Ύ','Y').replace('Ώ','Ω')}

